# How to find who was logged in before beginning of wtmp

Tags: linux, logging, login

I'm trying to determine who was recently logged into a specific machine in my office.  So I used `last`, but wtmp begins yesterday (Monday) around 14:30.  I was hoping to find info stretching back to Sunday, at least. Is there anyway to get that info without plodding through the authorization log file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Presumably your wtmp file has been rotated, so try `last -f /var/log/wtmp.1` or `last -f /var/log/wtmp.0` to read the previous files.  If those don't work, `ls /var/log/wtmp*` and see if they're called something else.  If they're compressed (`.gz` extension), decompress 'em.

If they're not there, find whoever setup the bollocks rotation scheme and give them a solid foot-punch to the pantaloons.  There's no reason not to keep at least a few weeks' of `wtmp` logs.

Comment: I really should have seen those rotated files in /var/log, I don't know how I missed them.

Answer (score 3):

If the wtmp files are not available, you can also look directly at /var/log/secure or /var/log/messages to see any login message in there.

Comment: I thought about that, but that's more work than I wanted to do, really.